# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory when running a react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I was using npm version 8.1.1 and node version 17.0.1. Then I tried downgrading to versions 7.24.2 for npm and 14.18.1 LTS for node, but I still get the same error.

````
[7432:000001F15002D0F0]   193144 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2037.2 (2051.1) -> 2036.8 (2052.4) MB, 3731.7 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.141, current mu = 0.017) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[7432:000001F15002D0F0]   196878 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2038.0 (2054.4) -> 2037.6 (2055.1) MB, 3724.3 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.080, current mu = 0.003) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF684FE412F napi_wrap+133311
 2: 00007FF684F7DD06 SSL_get_quiet_shutdown+63062
 3: 00007FF684F7EB9D node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF6858619CE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF6858467BD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF6856EFFCC v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF6856FB3EA v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1258
 8: 00007FF6856F8529 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2457
 9: 00007FF6856ED0C1 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2049
10: 00007FF6856EB2C5 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1349
11: 00007FF68570B73B v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+203
12: 00007FF685439F81 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1409
13: 00007FF6858ECDFD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+474253
14: 00007FF6858EDCAD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+478013
15: 00007FF68593DE89 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+806169
16: 00007FF6858DC792 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+407074
17: 0000031867B4B9AC ```
````

Comment: You can try running this command on the terminal on which you are running your project: ``NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"``

Comment: And inform here ehether it worked or not.

Comment: @VipulTyagi it doesn't work. both with npm and yarn. Even after I delete node_modules and run npm install

Comment: Please don't share screenshots of text. It's best to copy and paste the output into the post.

Comment: It means you're running out of memory. Fix your application to use less memory. If this is e.g. a CRA app, you could disable sourcemaps, because generating them uses a lot of memory.

Comment: @AKX. Thanks, disabling the sourcemaps definitely works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution that has worked for me is adding a `.env` file in the same directory as `package.json` and adding `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` into the `.env` file.

see this for reference https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

Comment: This fixed our OOM issue. Added This to our Dockerfile
ARG GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false